# How to calculate P(X=x|Y=y) using copula functions?

Tags: probability, copula

I want to get the conditional probability of P(U=u|V=v) or P(X=x|Y=y) using copulas.However, I found that if I use the copulapdf function of Matlab, the result is bigger than 1! I don't know why. any one could help me? thank very much for your help!

the formulas are following:
[image]

Comment: Show your code, maybe? My guess is that you're obtaining PDF with copula, not the probability.

Comment: Sorry, what is the different between PDF and probability? I want to know the probability of P(U=u|V=v). Thanks!

Comment: Probability is the area under [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). I'm suspecting that you're getting the value of PDF, not the area. That's why you should post your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have code. I am just constructing the formulas. Do you mean I can't get the probability of (U=u|V=v) directly. But I can get the probability of (U<u|V=v).

Comment: Show us how you construct these formulas.

Comment: may be I know my mistake: If a probability distribution admits a density, then the probability of every one-point set {a} is zero;

Comment: Sorry, do you understand my meaning?

Answer (score 1):

You probably got the problem by now: any probability of a point on real line for continuous distribution is going to be 0. So your denominator in last equation is 0.

Comment: Yes, that is my mistake. So  should I calculate the probability in an interval instead of one point?

Comment: @eric, you can compute the probability of one point for discrete distributions and discontinuous distributions (in some cases). For continuous, they're all going to be zeros, and only the intervals make a sense.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I think I should change the "=" to"<" or">". Thanks again!